# iOS project won't compile because it can't find pch file as I had to rename folders

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iOS development, and I was using this guy's oauth implementation:
https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth1,
so I built a project based on his project file for simplicity's sake. 
After a while I realised that I didn't like the folder structure, so I changed it by renaming some folders. I had to replace a bunch of files that came up red. Now I get these errors when I try to compile:

```
- Check dependencies: 
  Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's info.plist file '/Users/Manuel/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp-info.plist'

- Precompile MyApp-Prefix.pch ...in /Users/Manuel/Desktop/MyApp/Simple-OAuth1
  ... a bunch of ProcessPCH stuff here that I can't decipher

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Manuel/Desktop/MyApp/Simple-OAuth1/MyApp-Prefix.pch
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have changed the folder name from Simple-OAuth1 to MyApp. I replaced the prefix file so it's not red anymore. Is there some setting somewhere that I need to change to get it to work? I also tried cleaning the project.

Comment: Create a newfile with the missing filename. and add these line #ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: As the error says, it cannot find pch file. Look into build settings and search for precompiled headers. Rename the file name there and you are good to go.

Comment: You need to check Build Settings too. Search for pch entry, you can see some red line there..

Comment: k6sandeep you should have answered the question, you were right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. go to 'Build Phases' in your Target and remove the .plist file from 'Copy Bundle Resources'
2. go to 'BuildSettings' in your Target and search for 'Prefix Header' there you should check if the path is the same as your new/current .pch file

Comment: How will 1 fix the issue? First of the `.plist` doesn't appear under `Compile Sources` and even if it did based on what the `*-info.plist` file is used for and what `Compile Sources` actually does this would break the project. -1 based on your statement marked under 1.

Comment: @Popeye you're right so i corrected my post from Compile Sources to Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 6):

When you rename folders in your project sometimes you have to update the `Build Settings` in your project, especially when you rename the folders for things like `*-info.plist` and your `*-prefix.pch` files. But luckily this is simple to do following the below steps:

**Updating `*-prefix.pch` location**

1. Open your project up in xcode
2. Navigate to `Build Settings` for the `Target` you need to update.
3. In the `Build Settings` search bar type in `"Prefix Header"` or just `"pch"`.
4. Double click the value field for `Prefix Header` and enter the new location for your `*-prefix.pch` file.
5. Save.

**Updating `*-info.plist` location**

1. Open your project up in xcode.
2. Navigate to `Build Settings` for the `Target` you need to update.
3. In the `Build Settings` search bar type in `"Info.plist File"` or `"plist"`.
4. Double click the value field for `Info.plist file` and enter the new location of your `*-info.plist` file.
5. Save.

Comment: Also don't forget, if you have a bridging header to do the same as above looking for ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h and change it there.